# Best way to add elements to a list with a for-loop and a function?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, design-patterns

I have the following for-loop (it is a simplification of my real scenario, the function is way more complex)

```py
list_a = []
for b in list_b:
    if b.status != 'Approved':
        continue
    if b.something:
        continue
    list_a = add_elements_to_a_depending_on_b(b, list_a)
```

And the function looks like this. It can add one element or multiple to the list.

```py
def add_elements_to_a_depending_on_b(element_b, list_a = None):
    if list_a is None:
        list_a = []
    for i in range(element_b.multiple) 
        result = complex_api_call(element_b)
        list_a.append(result)
    return list_a
```

Is this pythonic? Which is the best way to implement this pattern? I would appreciate a link with supporting documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic thing would probably be to use a list comprehension:

```py
list_a = [b * 2 for b in list_b]
```

**EDIT:**
Even with all the new details shared, I'd still use a list comprehension, and a conditional statement to decide which elements to include:

```py
list_a = 
    [complex_api_call(b) for b in list_b if b.status == 'Approved' and not b.something]
```

Comment: I have simplified a lot my code. The operation inside the function is not as simple as `b*2`

Comment: @fullfine I'd still use a list comprehension. Replace `b * 2` with some `doSomething(b)` call that handles the logic for a single element.

Comment: Also note to return only the result from `doSomething(b)` instead of the entire list

Comment: Sorry for the oversimplification, the for-loop also has some checks that I think that discard the use of list-comprehension

Comment: @fullfine can you edit your question and share the relevant details? It's quite hard to help you without having the full picture.

Comment: Now I think I'm not leaving anything out

Comment: @fullfine See my edited answer - I'd still go with a list comprehension

Comment: I'm going to test it. I think that I can replace`b.status == 'Approved' and not b.something` with a function to keep it simple.

Comment: I have test it with a `list_a` of 100 elements and the results are quite similar. 1.18 vs 1.15 seconds. List comprehension is faster. However, I miss one last thing, `complex_api_call(b)` can return a single element or a list of elements, so I had to add another list comprehension to flat the resultant list.